# Twilio Friendly Verification From Name

Tags: twilio

I am using the Verification service and all working fine. My Service Name appears in the body of the Verification message correctly but how can I change the SMS From label?

In my SMS app I see a list of messages from various contacts and companies, the message from Twilio Verification Service shows as a 5 digit code e.g 12345. How can I change that from 12345 to "MyService"?

I get messages from other companies and a short company name appears as a contact name, how can I do the same with my twilio verification service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/verify) uses a variety of short codes, alphanumeric sender IDs and other phone numbers in order to send the verification messages around the world. The Verify team work on ensuring the numbers/sender IDs have the best possible delivery by pre-registering them in various countries. This gives you the highest possible chances of getting authentication messages delivered swiftly. You can't customise the number by default.

If you are looking to customise the number that is used, I would recommend you [talk to the Twilio sales team](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) to see what you can arrange.

Comment: From this support doc https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Change-the-From-number-or-Sender-ID-for-Sending-SMS-Messages it states "To use an alphanumeric sender ID for sending messages, input your ID in the From parameter of your API request". I have done this but the short code still appears instead? Am I missing something

Comment: Yep, that article is about [sending SMS messages with the messaging API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource) and it is not about [sending verification messages with Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification). [Creating a verification does not have a `From` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification#start-new-verification).

Comment: I have just stumbled upon this article on your support site https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS. Under the section "Limitations of Alphanumeric Sender IDs" it states "Sender IDs are only supported for paid Twilio accounts; not for free trial accounts" - can you verify this?

Comment: That is absolutely true, but you still can't change the number/alphanumeric sender ID via the Verify API.

Comment: Many thanks. I think this explains it and confirmation that you can't send it from the Verify API